# CSS mix-blend-mode in Chrome under Windows 7

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, blending

I haven't been able to find any information about this issue online, but I know for sure I'm not the only one with the problem. But under Windows 7, using Chrome 46 and with the following sample [in this website](http://www.sitepoint.com/close-up-css-mix-blend-mode-property/), I see this: 
[image: This is what I see]
When I should see this: 
[image: When I should see this]
Does anyone know if is possible to either fix the issue, or have it work only on the browsers that are not broken (Modernizr indicates that this browser supports it) and not apply it when under Windows 7?

Comment: "Enabled in Chrome through the "experimental Web Platform features" flag in chrome://flags"

Comment: I can't ask users to enable a browser feature... I was expecting the feature to be ignored if not available, but instead is making the boxes (with all their content) disappear completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome 46 for Windows (all versions). Some (but not all) blend modes are broken.

Chrome 46 for Mac is *not* affected.

You can read more about this in the Chromium issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543583

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to fix this, so the only solution is to avoid using `mix-blend-mode` until this bug is fixed in Chrome.